# BootstrapToggle checkbox call functions on click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am trying to attach some events to the new BootstrapToogle checkbox http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ but I can't figure where I am failing.

So basically I have a bootstrap toggle and I want to call some functions depending on the checked property (true or false):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="editor_draw_erase" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Draw" data-off="Erase" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">

$(function(){
    $("#editor_draw_erase").click(function() {
    var Toggle = document.getElementById('editor_draw_erase');
      if (Toggle.checked) {
        console.log("draw")
          //call some function
      } else {
        console.log("erase")
          //call some other functions
      }
    });

})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c7p9n62w/12/

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faces the same issue. It's because the library create his own elements and your checkbox is not really changed.

You can just look if your checkbox have the class `off`.

You can check this by inspecting the DOM when you check your checkbox.

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass("off")){
     console.log("draw")
  } 
  else{
     console.log("erase")
  }
});
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/c7p9n62w/13/)**

Comment: Merci. Any idea how to enable the checkbox through jQuery/JS if I set the default on "disabled" ? I tried $('.toggle').prop('disabled', false) but it didn't work.

Comment: @Roxanne if you look at the demo, you can use `$('#editor_draw_erase').bootstrapToggle('disable');` or `enable`

Comment: You've issues on your library include. It works https://jsfiddle.net/c7p9n62w/18/

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was using two different version of jQuery because one of my external libraries could only work with an older version.  The older version was incompatible with the bootstrapToggle(). Now I have to find a workaround that

Answer (score 1):

add one outer element to access it

```js
  var consoleLine = "<p class=\"console-line\"></p>";

  console = {
    log: function(text) {
      $("#console-log").append($(consoleLine).html(text));
    }
  };
  $(function() {
    $("#ids").on('click',function() {
    alert('hai');
    var Toggle = document.getElementById('editor_draw_erase');
      if (Toggle.checked) {
        console.log("draw")
          //call some function
      } else {
        console.log("erase")
          //call some other functions
      }
    });
  })
    


 //console.log("draw")
```

```html
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ids"><input type="checkbox" id="editor_draw_erase" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Draw" data-off="Erase" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger"></div>
<p>
State:
</p>
<div id="console-log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble too. This is what worked for me. I am using JQuery for the toggle, as I was having trouble getting the data-toggle attribute to work.

```
  $(function() {
    $('#toggle').bootstrapToggle({
      on: 'Edit Enabled',
      off: 'Edit Disabled'
    })

     $('#toggle').change(function() {
       if($(this).prop('checked')){
         $("#message").html("this is true");
       }
       else{
         $("#message").html("this is false");
       }
     })
  })
```

This uses JQuery to set the label as well as call/perform other actions on the toggle.